# Preview Issue Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

as already told in the title, I have an issue regarding the preview tool of Android Studio.
As I install the program, all works fine. I can create layouts and previewing them without any trouble. The problem comes when I restart my computer. Every time, the preview tool disappears (grey unselectable menu option and no other buttons to activate it around) and I can't manage to make it work again, unless I re-download Android Studio and I re-update the SDK. It's really annoying, because it's difficult to project a layout without restarting the computer, looking at what you are doing or loading it every time on the phone.

I've attached a screenshot, can anyone help me? Does anyone know a solution?

[image]

as you can see, there is no preview and no button to activate it

Comment: Related/dupe: [Layout preview not working in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17365015)

Answer (score 0):

What about clicking on the design tab at the bottom of the editor ?

[image]

Comment: I tryied too, but it remains stuck on "Loading Configuration" forever... I tryied to leave it loading for an hour, then I lost my patience. I don't know what to do, really.

Comment: AndroidStudio is not released yet... so this kind of bug may occurs. I strongly suggest you to use Intellij-12 Community Edition. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501741/android-programming-and-frameworks-ides-to-use/17501917#17501917)